# Simple AES encrypt/decrypt methods for .NET 6 and .NET Framework

Tags: c#, cryptography, aes

I wrote some AES encryption/decryption methods with the following requirements:

- Inputs should be easy-to-use strings.
- Something encrypted in a .NET 6
  app using these methods should be able to be decrypted in a .NET Framework 4.8 app using the same methods.
- I do NOT need military or banking grade encryption.
- I do NOT desire too many choices regarding `CipherMode`, `PaddingMode`, etc.
- Extra: rather than decrypt to just a `string`, I can also decrypt to a `SecureString`, which can be passed to a `NetworkCredential` constructor.

That said, I do want to emphasize that I am very much a novice regarding cryptography.  Thus my need to make something simple for me to use.  Also: the code shown works perfectly well for me in both .NET 6 and .NET Framework 4.8.

**SimpleAes6 Class**

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.IO;
using System.Security;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;

namespace Davin.Cryptography
{
    // The intent is not for military or banking grade cryptography, but something strong enough
    // to pass an internal company audit.  At the very least, it is far better using this than
    // storing plain text passwords in Config files, since that would immediately raise an audit flag.

#pragma warning disable IDE0063 // Use simple 'using' statement
#pragma warning disable IDE0090 // Use 'new(...)'

    public static class SimpleAes6
    {
        // The public outer or wrapper class "SimpleAes6" works with string inputs and outputs.    
        // The private inner class "AesHelper" works with byte arrays.

        // The suffix 6 was used since this was written and tested specifically for .NET 6.
        // It has been confirmed to work with .NET Framework 4.8, that is to say that 
        // cipherText encrypted from a .NET 6 application can be decrypted back to plainText
        // by a .NET Framework application using the same code base contained here.

        /// <summary>
        /// Simple AES encryption of a plain text string using the specified secret Key phrase and IV Salt.  
        /// The same Key phrase and IV Salt must be used later when you decrypt the cipher text back to plain text.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="plainText">The plain text you wish to encrypt to cipher text.</param>
        /// <param name="key">The secret key.  Minimum length = 8, Maximum Length = 128.</param>
        /// <param name="ivSalt">A secret salt for the initialization vector.  Minimum length = 8, Maximum Length = 128.</param>
        /// <returns>An encrypted cipher text string suitable for passwords to be stored safely into XML or JSON files.</returns>
        public static string Encrypt(string plainText, string key, string ivSalt)
        {
            ValidateString(plainText, nameof(plainText), minLength: 1);
            ValidateString(key, nameof(key), minLength: 8, maxLength: 128);
            ValidateString(ivSalt, nameof(ivSalt), minLength: 8, maxLength: 128);

            // Get the bytes of the respective strings
            byte[] plainBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plainText);
            byte[] keyBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key);
            byte[] ivBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(ivSalt);

            // Hash the Key with SHA256
            keyBytes = SHA256.Create().ComputeHash(keyBytes);

            byte[] bytesEncrypted = AesHelper.Encrypt(plainBytes, keyBytes, ivBytes);

            return Convert.ToBase64String(bytesEncrypted);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Decrypts the cipher text back to plain text using the same secret Key phrase and IV Salt that was
        /// previously used to encrypt.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="cipherText">A string encryped earlier using the same secret Key phrase and IV Salt.</param>
        /// <param name="key">The secret Key.  Minimum length = 8, Maximum Length = 128.</param>
        /// <param name="ivSalt">A secret salt for the initialization vector.  Minimum length = 8, Maximum Length = 128.</param>
        /// <returns>A plain text string.</returns>
        public static string DecryptToString(string cipherText, string key, string ivSalt)
        {
            ValidateString(cipherText, nameof(cipherText), minLength: 1);
            ValidateString(key, nameof(key), minLength: 8, maxLength: 128);
            ValidateString(ivSalt, nameof(ivSalt), minLength: 8, maxLength: 128);

            // Get the bytes of the string
            byte[] cipherBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(cipherText);
            byte[] keyBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key);
            byte[] ivBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(ivSalt);

            keyBytes = SHA256.Create().ComputeHash(keyBytes);

            byte[] bytesDecrypted = AesHelper.Decrypt(cipherBytes, keyBytes, ivBytes);

            return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytesDecrypted);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Decrypts the cipher text back to a SecureString using the same secret pass phrase and salt that was
        /// originally used to encryt the text.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="cipherText">A string encryped earlier using the same secret Key phrase and IV Salt.</param>
        /// <param name="key">The secret Key.  Minimum length = 8, Maximum Length = 128.</param>
        /// <param name="ivsalt">A secret salt for the initialization vector.  Minimum length = 8, Maximum Length = 128.</param>
        /// <returns>A SecureString or null.</returns>
        public static SecureString DecryptToSecureString(string cipherText, string key, string ivsalt)
        {
            return ToSecureString(DecryptToString(cipherText, key, ivsalt));
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Converts a String to a SecureString.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="value">A String.</param>
        /// <returns></returns>A SecureString.
        public static SecureString ToSecureString(string value)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value))
            {
                return null;
            }
            SecureString result = new SecureString();
            foreach (var character in value.ToArray<char>())
            {
                result.AppendChar(character);
            }
            result.MakeReadOnly();
            return result;
        }


        private static class AesHelper
        {
            // The public outer or wrapper class "SimpleAes6" works with string inputs and outputs.    
            // The private inner class "AesHelper" works with byte arrays.

            const int KeySize = 256;
            const int BlockSize = 128;
            const int Iterations = 1000;

            private static Aes CreateAesInstance(byte[] key, byte[] iv)
            {
                var aes = Aes.Create();

                aes.KeySize = KeySize;
                aes.BlockSize = BlockSize;

                var derived = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(key, iv, Iterations);
                aes.Key = derived.GetBytes(aes.KeySize / 8);
                aes.IV = derived.GetBytes(aes.BlockSize / 8);

                return aes;
            }

            public static byte[] Encrypt(byte[] bytesToBeEncrypted, byte[] key, byte[] iv)
            {
                byte[] encryptedBytes = null;

                using (var aes = CreateAesInstance(key, iv))
                {
                    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        using (var cs = new CryptoStream(ms, aes.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                        {
                            cs.Write(bytesToBeEncrypted, 0, bytesToBeEncrypted.Length);
                            cs.FlushFinalBlock();
                        }
                        encryptedBytes = ms.ToArray();
                    }
                }

                return encryptedBytes;
            }

            public static byte[] Decrypt(byte[] bytesToBeDecrypted, byte[] key, byte[] iv)
            {
                byte[] decryptedBytes = null;

                using (var aes = CreateAesInstance(key, iv))
                {
                    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        using (var cs = new CryptoStream(ms, aes.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                        {
                            cs.Write(bytesToBeDecrypted, 0, bytesToBeDecrypted.Length);
                            cs.FlushFinalBlock();
                        }
                        decryptedBytes = TrimZeroPadding(ms.ToArray());
                    }
                }

                return decryptedBytes;
            }

            private static byte[] TrimZeroPadding(byte[] array)
            {
                if (array == null || array.Length == 0)
                {
                    return null;
                }
                var lastZeroIndex = array.Length;
                for (int i = array.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
                {
                    if (array[i] == char.MinValue)
                    {
                        lastZeroIndex = i;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }
                return array.Where((item, index) => index < lastZeroIndex).ToArray();
            }

        } // private inner class

    } // public wrapper class

#pragma warning restore IDE0090 // Use 'new(...)'
#pragma warning restore IDE0063 // Use simple 'using' statement

} // namespace
```

**Example Usage**

```
string key = "Hello, World!";
string ivsalt = "Goodbye, cruel world.";
string plainText = "It's Howdy Doody Time!";
string cipherText = Davin.Cryptography.SimpleAes.Encrypt(plainText, key, ivsalt);
// roundTrip should exactly equal plainText
string roundTrip = Davin.Cryptography.SimpleAes.DecryptToString(cipherText, key, ivsalt);
```

**Review Concerns**

Besides all the implied `CR` concerns (style, naming, practices, etc), I have specific concerns about safety.  As mentioned, I am a novice with cryptography.  And I had to find a peaceful coexistence with the code base to be used equally in .NET 6 and .NET Framework.

The code works fine but I did struggle originally experimenting with various `CipherMode` and `PaddingMode`.  Eventually I settled on not specifying them at all with `AES`.  It works, its easy for me to use, and I do **not need it to be military grade**.  Still, I think its a good idea to have it be reviewed so that I can learn from others.  There is always room for improvement.